# AFNetworking 2.0 Picture Upload and JSON Return Error

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

My AFNetworking code does not seem to be uploading any image and text to the server, but when I attempt to upload the image to the PHP file, the Json return an error listed below, or Error Code 3840. Any ideas would be appreciated and let me know if you need more information.

```
-(void)upLoadImage
{ 
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://***.php"]];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 0.5);
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": self.pictureMessage.text};
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {


    //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"userfl" fileName:@"upload.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
}];


op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

}
```

PHP:

```
    <?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

if(!empty($_POST)) 
{

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/appphotos';

    $file = basename($_FILES['userfl']['upload.jpg']);

    $uploadfile = $directory . $file;

    echo 'message= '.$message;

    var_dump($_FILES);

    $randomPhotoID = md5(rand() * time());

    echo json_encode($file);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfl']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    {
    $response["success"];
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
    $response["failure"];
    echo json_encode($response);

}

}
else
{
    $response['Empty post data'];
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Error:

```
2013-12-23 01:06:45.720 Animal[13757:907] Success: message= array(1) {
  ["userfl"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "upload.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpeRVNwb"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(9613)
  }
}
""null ***** <6d657373 6167653d 20617272 61792831 29207b0a 20205b22 75736572 666c225d 3d3e0a20 20617272 61792835 29207b0a 20202020 5b226e61 6d65225d 3d3e0a20 20202073 7472696e 67283130 29202275 706c6f61 642e6a70 67220a20 2020205b 22747970 65225d3d 3e0a2020 20207374 72696e67 28313029 2022696d 6167652f 6a706567 220a2020 20205b22 746d705f 6e616d65 225d3d3e 0a202020 20737472 696e6728 31342920 222f746d 702f7068 70655256 4e776222 0a202020 205b2265 72726f72 225d3d3e 0a202020 20696e74 2830290a 20202020 5b227369 7a65225d 3d3e0a20 20202069 6e742839 36313329 0a20207d 0a7d0a22 226e756c 6c>
```

Comment: Can you paste a response from that JSON data ? Do you have proper headers set in response ?

Comment: Looks like your ressponse is not json

Comment: It should be.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes - encode PHP response as JSON data

Comment: I did. I set it to content/json in the header.

Comment: And you encoded it using json_encode right ? So why in response you have print_r instead of JSON format ?

Comment: No, where do you suggest I do that?  There isn't a print_r anywhere in the code, just echos.

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: Actually, check out this approach please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415469/afnetworking-picture-upload-script